# How to remove elements in an array based on their odd or even index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to sort an array by its odd and even index and then have its data displayed by passing it as a prop to another component.

Let me explain my workings:

I have an array called products (woocommerce data).

```
const products = [
  { attributes: [{ option: "size 1" }] },
  { attributes: [{ option: "size 2" }] },
  { attributes: [{ option: "size 3" }] }
];
```

I have set up a `.map()` function in which for every object in my array I will return a component like so;

```
let sizeVariations = products.map((product, index) => {
  return (
    <div key={index}>
      <Buttons
        sizeEven={product.attributes[0].option}
        sizeOdd={product.attributes[0].option}
      />
    </div>
  );
});
```

I would like to pass the sizes through this component as two different props `sizeEven` and `sizeOdd` which equal `product.attributes[0].option`.

But for `product.attributes[0].option` I would like to "pop" or filter out all the odd or even index's accordingly for each prop.

How can I go about doing this?

Currently I have this format (https://codesandbox.io/s/018488478p) which does not work as you can only pass one index in `evenArray` or `oddArray`.

Comment: You can use modulo `%` to compare if the index is odd or even. So something like `if (index %2 === 0) {};`.

Comment: I can't quite understand the question. Do you want to create buttons according to `option` here? As in your example, you want to show one "Size 1" button on the left and "Size2", "Size 3" buttons on the right?

Comment: yes @devserkan thats it exactly it. Even index objects would be red and odd would be blue https://codesandbox.io/s/018488478p . But despite separating the even index into its own array and calling it it does not map. In which I mean you can only call one of the even index objects of `evenArray`. So my questions was is there another way to do this which I do not have to create two separate arrays and I can simply call `products.attributes[0].options' and .pop() or something alike out the odd attributes and vice versa?

Comment: Sorry again, I asked my question wrong. Do you want "size1" and "size3" on the  left and "size2" on the right? It is confusing since indexes are even but size numbers odd here :)

Comment: @devserkan sorry but yes thats it . Size 1 and size 3 on the left and size 2 on the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how you want to do this but actually you don't need to create additional arrays. I'm not quite good with CSS but here how I do it with four elements. With three elements last one will be centered. At least functionality works, but I'm not sure about CSS.

**Update**

I've changed the code a little bit. I defined the `Buttons` component as a functional one instead of class. Actually, `App` also would be like that but there would be some state in the future. I moved the map operation into a separate function and move it outside of `return`. So we have a cleaner logic in `return` method.

Note: Do not use indexes for `key` as I used here. Use some other unqiue  values.

[See here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

> We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may
>   change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues
>   with component state. Check out Robin Pokorny’s article for an
>   in-depth explanation on the negative impacts of using an index as a
>   key. If you choose not to assign an explicit key to list items then
>   React will default to using indexes as keys.
>
> Here is an in-depth explanation about why keys are necessary if you’re
>   interested in learning more.

Also, if React version is new enough we can use a top `<React.Fragment>` and use one key.

```js
const Buttons = props => {
  const { products } = props;

  const renderOptions = () =>
    products.map((p, i) =>
      !( i % 2 )
             ? <div key={i} className="left">{p.attributes[0].option}</div>
             : <div key={i} className="right">{p.attributes[0].option}</div> );

  return <div className="container">{renderOptions()}</div>;
};

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const products = [
      { attributes: [{ option: "size 1" }] },
      { attributes: [{ option: "size 2" }] },
      { attributes: [{ option: "size 3" }] },
      { attributes: [{ option: "size 4" }] },
    ];
   
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Buttons products={products}  />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.left {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.right {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I think this falls into the "OP is trying to run before they crawl" scenario.

Comment: @Trasiva, maybe yes, but in any case if we can show the right way (of course if this is what OP wants) s/he can crawl better :) I understand the learners since I am one of them. But, I totally agree with you, basic knowledge comes first.

Comment: Thanks this is essentially what I was looking for. Much appreciated.

Comment: Ooo also @devserkan how come you have not included a `key={}` for the .map()?

Comment: You are welcome. I just forgot the `key` :) It is not mandatory but we should, really should use it. So, I've added it to my answer within the divs. But, if possible do not use indexes for keys as I did. Use some other unique values. Since this is just an example I used the index here. One last one, instead of defining two keys for two divs, you can use a top wrapping <React.Fragment> and use a single key there if your React version is new enough.

Comment: Glad to helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
 const products = [
    { attributes: [{ option: "size 1" }] },
    { attributes: [{ option: "size 2" }] },
    { attributes: [{ option: "size 3" }] }
  ];

  const evenArray = products.filter((product, index) => index % 2 )
```

We can use the [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to create a new array with the elements that pass the test that we supplied `(product, index) => index % 2`, which in this case: if our element index is divisible by 2. We can find this out by using the [modulus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_())

Comment: Perhaps add to this question what the modulo operator is, and how your code works. Generally on SO we don't just submit answers without explaining them.

Comment: Thanks @paul this is effectively what I've done here https://codesandbox.io/s/018488478p but with a for loop, however despite it successfully creating a new array for me with just even index objects. I cannot get it to show `evenArray.attributes[0].options` for each component outputted by the `.map()`. You can only do it by hand accessing each index as so: `evenArray[0].attributes[0].options` 'evenArray[1].attributes[0].options',` evenArray[2].attributes[0].options` etc. I need this data to be shown as the map happens. if that makes sense.

Comment: @Trasiva if you look here https://codesandbox.io/s/018488478p I do this. But in calling `evenArray[0].attributes[0].option` you access only one of the even index objects and not the rest. Hence why I asked is there away I don't have to make two new separate arrays (`evenArray` and `oddArray`) but call the parent array `products.attributes[0].option` and simply .pop() out the odd index objects (vice versa) or something as such, as I pass the prop: `sizeEven = {products.pop().attributes[0].option}, something like this?

Comment: @kadddeee Look at this code here https://jsfiddle.net/abmLju02/4/. It's because you've formed your attributes arrays incorrectly. Instead of `attributes: [{options: "size X"}]`, use `attributes: {options: "size X"}`.

Comment: I cannot do that the array comes from woocommerce it is a list of 12 products. The data comes out like this; `attributes: [{options: "size X"}]` from the api theres other things amongst the array I've just simplified things for example sake. Besides @Trasiva in your fiddle the only data being called is `'size 2'` which is index 1 which is odd despite the `evenArray` calling for even indexes ? But thank you for contributing!!

Comment: That's because `evenArray` doesn't keep the indexes that your `products` array does. However, if you're wanting to also keep track of the index, you're going to need to do some math for that. I think you need to spend some time understanding arrays before you keep working on this particular project.

Comment: Hmm, I'm kinda of confused lol. In you're fiddle I don't understand how `'size 2'` was being called when that is index 1 an odd number , doesn't `index % 2` mean theres no remainders and the number can be divided? If you have time to explain or could point me to right source that would be much appreciated!!